# Elasticsearch shard sizes not balanced

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ES index with 3 shards. As you can see, almost all data is contained in one shard, other two does not have much:

```
index1      0 p STARTED      650 190.5kb 10.25.242.35 TWO
index1      1 p STARTED 77722991  26.2gb 10.25.242.36 THREE
index1      2 p STARTED      880 334.5kb 10.25.242.34 ONE
```

Why is that and how can I change this? I could not find any information in the documentation :(

Index settings:

```
[~] # curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/index1/_settings?pretty'
{
  "index1" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1449624574889",
        "number_of_shards" : "3",
        "uuid" : "QxDOzeG6Qj2BNExZ0z-Drg",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "1050299"
        },
        "number_of_replicas" : "0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

ES version is 1.5 and currently I cannot update it.

Comment: Are you maybe routing documents to that one shard when indexing? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can we see your indexing request ?
You are maybe routing documents when indexing them.

Comment: There is no routing at all.

Comment: Did you install some plugins on Elasticsearch ?

Comment: Turns out there WAS a routing set up, should have checked better :)